# Unsure how to model a many-to-many relationship with a flag in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have two entities, projects and users. These are modeled in Rails using Mongoid with two Document instances, User and Project.

In this system, one user can create one project, but many users can follow many projects. For example, as user_id 1 I've created project_id 1. But user_ids 10, 11, 40, and 60 all follow project_id 1. I need to represent a many-to-many relationship between users and projects, and represent a specific user_id as the creator of the project, to assign him editing rights.

Practically speaking, when a user logs-in, he needs to be able to see all projects that he is following, including any that he created, commingled with other projects created by other users. His special creator status wont influence this list at all. When a user looks at a specific project, he needs to be able to view all users following a project, and if he's a creator, he can add new followers and delete existing ones.

In a RDBMS I would represents this with tables `users`, `projects` and a `users_projects` join table with a flag of `is_creator`. This would easily let me select which projects a user can see, and which users are followers, including which users are creators, of projects.

Mongoid supports many-to-many relationships, but unlike in an RDBMS there's no way for me to put a flag on the relationship. Instead, I'm thinking I'll add a `creator` field to the `projects` document, which will contain a link back to an `_id` field on the users document.

The user->projects relationship might look like this

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end

class Project
  has_and_belongs_to_many: users
end
```

But I can't figure out how to map the creator->created_projects relationship. I believe I can reference a user creator in `Project` like `belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'` but I'm not sure how to set up the other side.

How best can I model these relationships in Mongoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an embedded document which holds all followers with their user_id and their username so you won't have to query the follower's usernames.

The benefits:

- Not a single query to lookup a project's followers
- Only a single query to lookup a user's followed projects

The downside:

- If a user changes his name, you'll have to update all his "followships" but how often 
  do you change your name compared to how often you lookup your followed projects ;)
- If you have many thousand followers per project you may reach the document limit of 16mb

**user.rb**

```
class User
  # projects this user owns
  has_many :projects

  def followed_projects
    Project.where('followers.user_id' => self.id)
  end

  # get projects that this user has created and projects he is following
  def related_projects
    Project.any_of({:user_id  => self.id}, {'followers.user_id' => self.id})
  end
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project
  # creator
  belongs_to :user

  embeds_many :followers

  # add an index because we're going to query on this
  index 'followers.user_id'

  # adds a follower
  # maybe you want to add some validations, preventing duplicate followers
  def add_follower!(user_obj)
    self.followers.create({
      :user       => user_obj,
      :username   => user_obj.username
    })
  end

  def remove_follower!(user_obj)
    self.followers.destroy_all(:conditions => {:user_id => user_obj.id})
  end

end
```

**follower.rb**

```
class Follower
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :project

  # reference to the real user
  belongs_to :user

  # cache the username
  field :username, :type => String
end
```

How to work with it:

```
@project    = Project.first
@some_user  = User.last

@project.add_follower!(@some_user)

@some_user.followed_projects
@some_user.related_projects

@project.followers.each do |c_follower|
  puts "I'm #{c_follower.username} and I'm following this project!"
end

@all_follower_user_ids = @project.followers.map{|c| c.user_id}

# find a specific follower by user_id 
@some_follower = @project.followers.where(:user_id => 1234)
# find a specific follower by username
@some_follower = @project.followers.where(:username => 'The Dude')

@project.remove_follower!(@some_user)
```

PS: If you want a simpler solution, you could just embedd an array of ObjectIDs (user_ids) in the project and use the atomic updates `$addToSet` and `$pullAll` to add/remove a follower. But you'd need an extra query like `User.where(:user_id.in => @project.follower_ids)` (assuming the array is called `follower_ids`) to grab all users and their names ;)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Question though, I've tried implementing this using your alternate suggestion, of storing user_id ObjectIDs on the projects document, but a stuck defining the relationships in projects and users. Would you mind posting an example of that solution too?

Answer (score 2):

the second version uses less space but you need an extra query to get the user details like usernames. An object ID has 12bytes, max. document size is 16mb so the array could hold around 1.3M user ids (theoretically!)..

here you go:

**user.rb**

```
class User
  # projects this user owns
  has_many :projects
  has_many :followed_projects, 
           :class_name => 'Project', 
           :foreign_key => :follower_ids

  # Uncomment if the relation does not work
  #def followed_projects
  #  Project.where(:follower_ids => self.id)
  #end

  # get projects that this user has created and projects he is following
  def related_projects
    Project.any_of({:user_id  => self.id}, {:follower_ids => self.id})
  end
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project
  # creator
  belongs_to :user

  field :follower_ids, :type => Array

  # adds a follower
  def add_follower!(user_obj)
    # adds a user uniquely to the follower_ids array
    self.add_to_set(:follower_ids, user_obj.id)
  end

  def remove_follower!(user_obj)
    # remove the user
    self.pull(:follower_ids, user_obj.id)
  end
end
```

How to work with it:

```
@project    = Project.first
@some_user  = User.last

@project.add_follower!(@some_user)

@some_user.followed_projects
@some_user.related_projects

# create hash like @ids_to_user[user_id] = user
@ids_to_users = User.find(@project.follower_ids).inject({}) {|hsh, c_user| hsh[c_user.id] = c_user; hsh}

@project.followers.each do |c_follower|
  puts "I'm #{@ids_to_users[c_follower].username} and I'm following this project!"
end

@project.remove_follower!(@some_user)
```